# Why italic doesn't work on Japanese font in CKEditor 5

Tags: html, ckeditor5, italic

Now, I am using CKEditor 5 12.0. 
I want to know why italic doesn't work on Japanese Font?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYRjo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the font used on that website does not support italic. Or the website is styled incorrectly (`<strong>`'s styles are reset). Those are the most probable reasons. Without more details it's impossible to guess, though.